# Cobertura de Testes Unitários no Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, tdd, phpunit

Ao iniciar um repositório com uma instalação nova do Laravel 5.5 e configurar a cobertura de testes e o Coveralls para isso, apesar de ter apenas feito o scaffold da autenticação do framework e não ter escrito nem uma única linha de código o retorno é que tem apenas 33.33% de cobertura de testes com o seguinte relatório:

---

Found 13 source files:

- 100.00% app/Console/Kernel.php
- 0.00% app/Exceptions/Handler.php
- 0.00% app/Http/Controllers/Auth/ForgotPasswordController.php
- 0.00% app/Http/Controllers/Auth/LoginController.php
- 0.00% app/Http/Controllers/Auth/RegisterController.php
- 0.00% app/Http/Controllers/Auth/ResetPasswordController.php
- 0.00% app/Http/Controllers/HomeController.php
- 0.00% app/Http/Middleware/RedirectIfAuthenticated.php
- 100.00% app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php
- 100.00% app/Providers/AuthServiceProvider.php
- 0.00% app/Providers/BroadcastServiceProvider.php
- 100.00% app/Providers/EventServiceProvider.php
- 100.00% app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php
  Coverage:  33.33% (24/72)

---

Todas essas classes provavelmente devem estar com cobertura de testes no repositório do framework. A pergunta seria, devo fazer os testes unitários para todas essas classes não cobertas na minha própria suíte de testes ou procurar desabilitar a verificação da cobertura de testes para essas classes? Principalmente as do próprio framework como BroadcastServiceProvider, Handler, etc?

---

https://github.com/renanoliveira0/Where.is.My.Money
https://coveralls.io/github/renanoliveira0/Where.is.My.Money

Comment: Eu não creio ser necessário testes nestas classes e aproveitando também não creio que seja necessário testes em CRUD, em crud.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Todas essas classes provavelmente devem estar com cobertura de testes
>   no repositório do framework.

Provavelmente sim, mas tome cuidado pois essas classes tem como objetivo serem customizadas para o seu projeto. Caso você adicione mais código nelas, pode ser interessante testá-lo caso julgue necessário.

> Devo fazer os testes unitários para todas essas classes não cobertas
>   na minha própria suíte de testes ou procurar desabilitar a verificação
>   da cobertura de testes para essas classes?

Aí é uma decisão para o seu projeto. A cobertura do código por testes unitários é uma métrica interessante para avaliar a qualidade do código, mas focar em chegar nos 100% não é um sinônimo de qualidade.

No caso do seu projeto, um único testes que acessa a home já garantiu um coverage de 33%. Excluindo esse tipo de teste, que não é considerado um teste unitário, o coverage do projeto cai para 0%.

Procure diversificar a suite de testes automatizados, de forma que você tenha testes de integração entre os componentes, testes de aceitação de um fluxo como um todo interagindo como um usuário, entre outros.

No caso do Laravel, gosto de deixar a lógica da aplicação inteiramente fora de `app`, dentro de um diretório `src`, totalmente desacoplado do *framework*, e só gero o *coverage* com testes unitários do código em `src`. O restante garanto com outros tipos de testes, como aceitação e integração.

Mas novamente, é uma questão de arquitetura da aplicação e a equipe que deve decidir como a métrica será aplicada.

O conselho que deixo é: não foque somente em ter coverage, mas também na diversificação da sua suite de testes. *Coverage* é apenas uma das possíveis métricas. Se mesmo com um *coverage* alto você não confie na sua suite de testes, só será um esforço perdido.

> Principalmente as do próprio framework como BroadcastServiceProvider,
>   Handler, etc?

A partir do momento que você executou um `composer create-project` ou `laravel new`, eu considero que esses arquivos não são mais de responsabilidade do *framework*, mas sim do seu projeto. Aqui vale o ponto acima: teste unitariamente se você tiver algo que valha a pena, e não somente para alcançar *coverage*.